# Twitter on Android (how to get Date and time of the feed )

Tags: android, twitter-feed

Actually i am making an android application which is integrated with the Twitter Feeds.
As i am able to get the corresponding tweets(feeds) of a specific user by the parsing of a JSONArray, which is coming from the twitter server.
But the DATE and TIME of those feeds is not there in that JSONAarray(response).

So do any one know, how to get the DATE and TIME of corresponding twitter feeds.

The code which I am using for getting the feeds is:

```
package com.tweet.example;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
public class Home extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String readTwitterFeed = readTwitterFeed();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readTwitterFeed);
            Log.i(Home.class.getName(),
                    "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i(Home.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("text"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String readTwitterFeed() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/<USERNAME>.json");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(Home.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:  Please give some working username @  ("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/.json");)

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm the timestamp is totally there, it's in the `created_at` field. Take a look at http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/gruber.json.